# different css style only for children of a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what I have:
I have a div `id="navbar"` and various styles for the `ul` and `li` elements there.

Now I want to know, if there is any selector in CSS where I can say "the following css-styles shall only be aplliedd to children of #navbar"

something like:

```
/* ***** NAVBAR ****** */
#navbar {
    /* Add a gray right border to all list items, except the last item (last-child) */
    li {
        border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
    }

    li:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }

    .active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    /* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
    li a:hover {
        background-color: #111;
    }
}
```

are there any ways to apply various css-styles only to elements that are chil or child-child or child-..-child of a certain HTML-element?

Note I'm also using jQuery so if thats only possible with jQuery, it will not be a problem.

sincerly basti

Comment: `#example > * {}` will select only direct children

Comment: The answer will be different if you mean ALL Children (in all levels), or only the next level of children. @Martijn has given the best answer I believe.

Comment: @Lee: *"...only to elements that are chil or child-child or child-..-child of a certain HTML-element?"* Clearly the OP is referring to descendants, not direct children.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fair enough

Comment: i guess a very tiny small search looking about CSS selector and you will end up with the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [*descendant combinator*](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#descendant-combinators): A space. For instance:

```
#navbar li {
    /* styles */
}
```

That will only apply the styles to `li` elements that are descendants of `#navbar`.

You have to use it on every rule. If you want syntax more like what you have in your question, there are preprocessors that do that sort of thing: [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), [Less](http://lesscss.org/), and such.

But with just CSS itself, you need to repeat the `#navbar` on every rule.

Answer (score 0):

**Direct Children**

```
#parent > #child {
    color: #fff;
}
```

**Descendants**

```
#parent #descendant {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder a descendant (in first class) is a child of an element aswell, isnt it ? ;)